# Kendo DataSource $expand on multiple fields

Tags: kendo-ui, odata

I'm trying to get the `$expand` directive to work as below.

This works fine if I expand on on a single entity, but fails for both when expanding on more than one. (i.e. `$expand: "Product"`, works works fine)

Anyone succeeded with this?

```
  dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "odata/OrderDetail",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: {
                            $expand: ["Product", "Category"]
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$expand: "Product,Category"`

I assumed that "$expand" was built into KUI datasource.  But the  `data:{ }` param. allows arbitrary specification (which it injects into the request).

So, one can use `$mickeymouse`, and long as your odata controller handles it